# How to trigger an EventKit alarm with Coordinates in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, eventkit

I don't know about anyone else, but EventKit seems to have very little in terms resources and tutorials online for you to refer to for help.

I need to trigger an alarm when a user hits a radius of a set of coordinates, I wasn't sure of the best ay to do this, I was torn between local notifications, and EventKit reminders.

I decided to go for eventKit as I felt that I could do more with more the alarms and it was the most practical way to do it however, having not known much about EventKit i had some issues.

Anyway I've managed to get together and build a sample project which works and triggers an alert when the user leaves their current location, the only problem is, is that I almost want to do the complete opposite of that, I want to trigger an alert when the user enters a set of coordinates, I assume that most of the code is transferrable, however I seem to be stuck on one bit mainly.

```
// Creates an EKStructuredLocation Instance with a title of "Current Location"
    let location = EKStructuredLocation(title: "Current Location")
    // Uses the last location update extracted from the locations array to supply you're current location
    location.geoLocation = locations.last as! CLLocation


    // Location is added to a newly created alarm instance
    let alarm = EKAlarm()
    alarm.structuredLocation = location
    // This alarm is triggered when the user moves away from the location proximity
    alarm.proximity = EKAlarmProximityLeave
    stationReminder.addAlarm(alarm)
```

I'm struggling to find how to set the location of the alarm to coordinates rather than users location.

I tried changing this

```
location.geoLocation = locations.last as! CLLocation
```

to

```
location.geoLocation = CLCircularRegion(circularRegionWithCenter: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.33233141, longitude: -122.03121860), radius: 50.0, identifier: "Location1")
```

but this doesn't work, i believe i am on the right track but i am throwing up this error: `Cannot assign a value of type 'CLCircularRegion!' to a value of type 'CLLocation!'`

I've tried loads of things with no resolve, does anybody have any experience with this and know how to help?

I also assume i'll have to change the following from this

```
alarm.proximity = EKAlarmProximityLeave
```

to this

```
alarm.proximity = EKAlarmProximityEnter
```

UPDATE

I've taken on board some comments below and tried a bunch of other things to get this to work, I feel like I am so close but somethings just missing. I cannot get this alarm to trigger. Excuse all the code comments, it's just so you can see some of the attempts i have made at fixing this.

can anyone see anything wrong with this code for the alarm?

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    // Stops location manager from sending further updates
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    // Creates a new EKReminder which is named and initialised with text from the UITextField
    let stationReminder = EKReminder(eventStore: appDelegate!.eventStore)
    stationReminder.title = locationText.text

    // Stores the previously created EKReminder in the default calendar
    stationReminder.calendar = appDelegate!.eventStore!.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()

    // Creates an EKStructuredLocation Instance with a title of "Current Location"
    let location = EKStructuredLocation(title: "Destination: Bournemouth Station")
    // Uses the last location update extracted from the locations array to supply you're current location
//        location.geoLocation = locations.last as! CLLocation
//        location.geoLocation = CLCircularRegion(circularRegionWithCenter: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.33233141, longitude: -122.03121860), radius: 50.0, identifier: "Location1")
//        location.geoLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 50.742771, longitude: -1.895072)
    location.radius = 50.0

    location.geoLocation = CLLocation(latitude:50.742771, longitude:-1.895072)
//        location.radius = 10.0 // metres

    // Location is added to a newly created alarm instance
    let alarm = EKAlarm()
    alarm.structuredLocation = location
    // This alarm is triggered when the user moves away from the location proximity
//        alarm.proximity = EKAlarmProximityEnter
    alarm.proximity = EKAlarmProximityEnter // "geofence": we alarm when *arriving*
    // but this will have no effect until Reminders is granted Location access...
    // and in iOS 8 it won't even ask for it until it is launched
    // also, in iOS 8 the separate background usage pref is withdrawn;
    // instead, auth of Reminders for "when in use" covers this...
    // ...because it means "this app *or one of its features* is visible on screen"
    stationReminder.addAlarm(alarm)

    // Now we have a fully configured reminder which we save in the Event Store
    var error: NSError?
    appDelegate!.eventStore?.saveReminder(stationReminder,
        commit: true, error: &error)

    if error != nil {
        println("Reminder failed with error \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like EKEvent has an `EKStructuredLocation`, which you are using correctly. However, you need to be careful of the type of the geoLocation property. It should be a CLLocation, which is not the same as a CLCircularRegion.

Steps to fix:

1. check the docs for `EKStructuredLocation`  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKStructuredLocationClassRef/index.html
2. set the location.geoLocation to a CLLocation that you create from latitude, longitude coordinates. (check the docs for `CLLocation`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/CLLocation)
   `geoLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 37.33233141, longitude: -122.03121860)`
3. set the geoLocation.radius separately `location.radius = 50.0`
4. at that point setting `proximityEnter` should work as you expected

Comment: Sorry, I should of made it clearer in the post, It's the `EKStructuredLocation` that I'm struggling to get working with CLLocationManager, I've tried so many things but i just don't understand it

Comment: Try steps 2 and 4 from my answer. They will fix this error:  "Cannot assign a value of type 'CLCircularRegion!' to a value of type 'CLLocation!'". Then edit your question if you need more help.

Comment: great. This looks like it should set an stationalarm in the appdelegate's event store. The stationalarm should fire when the user gets within 50m of the lat,lon geoLocation. Now I have two questions:  1) how are you testing it? 2) what "doesn't work"?

Comment: I've tested the coordinates by inputting ones 150metres away and then i am walking to the correct place in order to test, which as you can imagine is a rather tedious task. it seems that the event is storing to the reminders, however no alarm or anything at all is happening when you reach the radius, which makes me think something to do with location isn't set up right

Comment: Sounds like a bummer. I'm going offline, but here's a couple of tips for now:  - add some logging so you can see in the console when an event is fired.

Comment: and use CustomLocations in the simulator:  Run your app in the simulator, choose Debut > Location > Custom Location. Input the location.  It will probably be handy to have a list of inside / outside the geofence locations to just copy and paste as needed.

Comment: that should give you the tools to make some progress. Also, don't forget to use the docs. Sometimes they're even better than a tutorial.